INNERHTML de JS
Quiero agregar un botón con un archivo pdf que abrirá una nueva ventana del navegador: no me permite ya que el código es en js y mi botón es en html.
Agregué una propiedad INNERHTML. ¿Estaría en lo correcto agregarlo dentro del INNERHTML, o es incorrecto?
if (datos[0] == 'error') {
  document.getElementById('mapsecc').innerHTML = "NO <strong>EXISTE</strong> LA SECCIÓN";
} else if (datos[0] == 'baja') {
  document.getElementById('mapsecc').innerHTML = "<a href="
  https: //devscmgel.iecm.mx/wp-content/uploads/2024/10/EQUIVALENCIAS_SECCIONES_BAJA_ALTA.pdf">SI TU CREDENCIAL ESTÁ EN LA SIGUIENTE SECCIÓN, <strong>CONSULTA LA INFORMACIÓN ANEXA.</a></strong>";
}


hay muchisima interaccion entre js y html, sobre todo porque js se utiliza para modificar el html.. asi que no me deja no es del todo creible.. nos mostras que trataste de hacer que no te "deja"

Al momento de que ejecute la opcion "baja" debe salir una leyenda y vincular con un archivo PDF

Intenta usando ' en lugar de "

Muchas gracias Alan si me funcionó

Te recomiendo que cambies la url que colocaste por una dummy. Recuerda que el sitio es scrapeado por miles de robots diariamente...

Para solucionarlo, podes alternar entre comillas dobles y simples como te muestro a continuación:
document.getElementById('mapsecc').innerHTML = '<a href="https://devscmgel.iecm.mx/wp-content/uploads/2024/10/EQUIVALENCIAS_SECCIONES_BAJA_ALTA.pdf">SI TU CREDENCIAL ESTÁ EN LA SIGUIENTE SECCIÓN, <strong>CONSULTA LA INFORMACIÓN ANEXA.</strong></a>';

En esta línea, uso comillas simples para delimitar la cadena en JavaScript y comillas dobles para los atributos href y strong en HTML.
